# How can I optimize this query used by a cursor?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, cursor, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a stored procedure that utilizes the below cursor :

```
DECLARE Delai_latence CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
SELECT [ID]
      ,[ID_LIVRAISON]
      ,[DH_ETAPE_DEB]
      ,[DH_ETAPE_FIN]
      ,[ORDRE_ETAPE]
FROM [ODS_PFNUM_DELAI]
WHERE ID_GRP = 1
  AND STATUT_ETAPE is not Null
  AND DH_ETAPE_FIN is not Null
ORDER BY [ID_LIVRAISON], [ORDRE_ETAPE]
```

In order to optimize it, I created the non-clustered index :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LATENCE_PFNUM_DELAI] ON [ODS_PFNUM_DELAI] 
(
    [ID_GRP] ASC,
    [STATUT_ETAPE] ASC,
    [DH_ETAPE_FIN] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [ID],
[ID_LIVRAISON],
[DH_ETAPE_DEB],
[ORDRE_ETAPE]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

However, the execution is still taking too much time (you'll find attached the execution plan).

Thanks.

[ExecutionPlan.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfchO.jpg)

Comment: If you are using 2012 or 2014, you may be able to replace your cursor entirely, by using the window functions. This could give you a big performance increase. Functions like Lag, Lead and the unbound preceding predicate are going to be your friends.

Comment: @NeilP Unfortunately, I'm using SQL Server 2008. Thanks for your response anyway!

Comment: It is very rare for you genuinely to need a cursor, could you provide a bit more background, so that perhaps we can optimise out the cursor. You will find that set based queries rather than RBAR (row by agonising row) are often much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The real question probably is: do you really need a cursor, especially given the 'fat' lines shown in the Query Plan.

Anyway, out of curiosity, would the query benefit from this (filtered) index ?

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON [ODS_PFNUM_DELAI] 
       ([ID_GRP], [ID_LIVRAISON], [ORDRE_ETAPE]) 
INCLUDE ([ID], [DH_ETAPE_DEB], [DH_ETAPE_FIN])
WHERE [STATUT_ETAPE] IS NOT NULL AND [DH_ETAPE_FIN] IS NOT NULL
```

Also, not having a clue about the rest of your stored procedure: if you'd happen to be updating the `[ODS_PFNUM_DELAI]` table inside the cursor loop and the changes don't affect the actual loop, it might be a good idea to define the cursor as `STATIC`.